# Pre/post delete events aren't fired on refclass (many-to-many) in doctrine

Tags: events, doctrine, many-to-many

Is this a bug in Doctrine, or my wrong interpretaion?

PS: Pre/post save events are fired correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the save() cascade, the delete cascade needs to be turned on explicitly:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/defining-models:transitive-persistence:application-level-cascades:delete-cascades